# What is the use of UPS Sizing?

Tags: ups

UPS sizing as I have read in the internet is a simple mathematical formula multiplying power (volts) and current (amps) to eventually come up with the load rating VA (volts x amps).
The answer i got for the question i asked previously was Sizing of UPS and the answer seemed pretty reasonable. But What actually is this UPS Sizing and Why it is used?

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to know? Why there are UPSs with different load capacity? Why PCs draw different amounts of power?

Comment: Yes sir.Actually I just want to know how can i relate the solution given by a User to my UPS Problem so that i can make a further step in solving it.Go to the above link so that u will come to know about it

Comment: You haven't stated the rating on the current one you are using. What is the UPS rated at?

Comment: @cybernard - My apologies, but what you are saying is incorrect.  VA does nothing to determine runtime - it determines maximum load.  It is possible to have a 500va UPS (for example with extended battery packs) outlast a 1500va UPS, for example - but plug in computers that draw 10 amps at 120 volts and the 500va UPS won't work while the 1500va one should cope.    Of-course in practice, if you have a 1500va UPS with only 500va load you would reasonably expect it to run longer as the batteries are not draining as fast - and it will likely have biger batteries to handle the expected load.

Comment: In my mind if you have extended battery packs you have just increased the VA to match the number and size of the extended batteries.

Comment: @cybernard - rather late (I did not see this comment because it was not addressed to me), but VA rating and battery size are unrelated.  I can have a UPS with a VA rating of 2kVA and runtime of 20 minutes and a 1kVA unit with a rating of 60 minutes - if I try and put 2kVA load on the 1kVA unit it won't work, while it will work fine on the 2kVA unit with less runtime.

Answer (score 1):

UPS Sizing is about having a UPS which can do what it needs to do.

If, for example you have 10 servers, each pulling 100 watts of power, and you plug them into a 500va UPS, the UPS will simply not be able to provide them the resources they need when the power is off, and you may as well not have a UPS.

UPS sizing is no more then ensuring that it is fit for purpose - this is done by working out the load and required runtime and making sure the UPS is large enough to handle it - but not so large that you are paying way more then you need to for extra capacity.